# Getting JSON Value

Tags: php, json, parsing

I've been having issues trying to get the value "next_page_token". This is what the beginning of my JSON thats returned looks:

```
 {
   "html_attributions" : [],
 "next_page_token" : "ClRNAAAAk2Non5ZQxKrypNJczx2OQmUeAaIvcQCxvL15dsCR2KTovsxEyaU5wz7MxnUnuPEJxqB8d3xqDBYbprTm3LarTrFRypEZXSMPqfrpJ8UeeKISEGIF2iDgdGtVFNlQLnfFcPUaFG8P1cP-4TJNg2ezNE2vb2VSTynh",
 "results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 21.397577,
           "lng" : -157.727096
        }
```

This is what Im using to trying to Parse it, I have no issues parsing the rest of the JSON values just cant parse "next_page_token" for some weird reason:

```
foreach(json_decode($response) as $item){
     echo $pagetoken = $item->next_page_token;
     echo '<br>';
     $pagetoken ='&pagetoken='.$pagetoken.'';
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your proper `JSON` data ?

Comment: `json_decode($response)->next_page_token`

Comment: You didn't see any errors?

Comment: Barmar Solved it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is not an array, it's just a single object, so you don't need `foreach`.

```
$item = json_decode($response);
$pagetoken = $item->next_page_token;
```

In JSON, arrays are in `[...]`, objects are in `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `foreach`.

```
$item = json_decode($response);
$pagetoken = $item->next_page_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
echo $pagetoken = json_decode($response)->next_page_token;
```

since `$response` is an object, not an array.